# Jquery: can event.target ever be undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Say you have some click handler for example:

```
$('#someElement').click(function(_event) { ... });
```

Can _event.target ever be undefined? Is there any point in having some check like:

```
if(_event.target && someOtherCondition) {
 // do something with _event.target
}
```

Comment: You're asking specifically about jQuery's `event` object and not native events, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can't trigger an event without an originating element. See the manual page for [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger). [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) will always therefore be set.